# Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame. - Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, web, window.open, window.location

Help, I want to create a Site where you can visit what an user is doing in a Window...

My code:

```
<script>
    google = window.open("https://www.google.com/")
    
    function getLocation() {
         console.log(google.location.href)
    }
</script>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Get Location</button>
```

But I always get the output:

```
main.html:5 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at getLocation (file:///C:/Users/*****/Desktop/main.html:5:42)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (file:///C:/Users/*****/Desktop/main.html:8:37)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: "I want to create a Site where you can visit what an user is doing in a Window" ... what does it even mean? anyway you should read about `cross-origin policy` (google it). Google doesn't allow cross domain requests.

Comment: "*I want to create a Site where you can visit what an user is doing in a Window...*" Ah, so you're trying to invasively violate users' privacy? Great! /s